# Persistent unwanted space between labels

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button, label

I've been trying to eliminate the space between these two labels, which I'd like to be side-by-side, to no avail. I've checked the way jQuery UI does it, but as far as I can tell their CSS is the same as mine. What am I missing?

```
.buttonset label {
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #eee;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.buttonset label.checked {
    border: 2px solid #5dccdb;
    color: #5dccdb;
    font-style: italic;
}
.buttonset input[type='radio'] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jboneca/w76rM/2/)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: try with adding float property as .buttonset label{float: left;}

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have `checked` set as the class for the 2nd label. It just says `checked` where it should say `class="checked"`, I presume.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah, I tried to rid the code of all superfluous stuff. In the full code the label has class="checked"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the white space between the labels in your HTML:

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/w76rM/4/

There are several ways to do it, three of the quickest ones are to comment out the white space, have all the elements in one line or have the ending `>` of the previous tag at the beginning of the next line.

1 -In one line:

```
 <Label>...</label><Label>...</label>
```

2- Commented out:

```
   <Label></label><!--
--><Label></label>
```

3- `>` of previous tag at the beginning of the next line:

```
   <Label></label
   ><Label></label>
```

Your markup with commented out white space:

```
<div class="buttonset one_half"> 
    <div>Twins</div>
    <label for="twins_yes">
        <input id="twins_yes" name="twins" type="radio" value="Yes">Yes</label><!--
    --><label for="twins_no" class="checked">
        <input id="twins_no" name="twins" type="radio" value="No" checked>No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Who would have guessed that a space would cause a space :)? I'm an idiot, will accept answer when time elapses.

Comment: @jboneca Glad to be of help to you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add float left to the label elements

```
.buttonset label {
        width: 45%;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 2px solid #eee;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    float: left;    }
```